# How can I seed a counter instrument when migrating towards OTel counters?

Tags: monitoring, metrics, open-telemetry

Imagine a business metric that is currently being tracked by an in-house tool somewhere, let's call it "hats sold": whenever an order is processed in my application, the number of hats sold in the order is persisted alongside the date of the event. This data is later aggregated in a custom UI so that business can tell at any given time how our sales are going using graphs and totals.

For this example, consider that as of today, this "hats sold" value is sitting at 420 total, and that this was reached in 10 orders of 42 hats each: one per month.

Now imagine I want to move away from the in-house solution, and into a custom OpenTelemetry metric, using a COUNTER instrument to keep historical track of the "hats sold" value. If I just change my code to stop tracking the value manually and instead push increments to a `Counter` instance, this counter will start counting from 0 again on whatever monitoring tool I'm using: this only makes sense, since these would be the first emissions of the counter from the monitoring tool's perspective.

How do I ensure that, when migrating to the OpenTelemetry approach, that my counter starts counting from 420 (the value I had prior to the migration) instead of from 0? And what about my historical sales data, how would I "migrate" that when converting the logic to OpenTelemetry-based? In other words, how do I "seed" historical counter data?

Comment: Would this aggregation not be done on a sink (collector sink in any metrics system). The application could restart and these counters (in the application code) could get reset again anyway as the metrics are "stateless" in a true sense

Comment: @Ramachandran.A.G each metric emitted is stateless, but when you are creating a graph or reporting, you define a period of time where the counters are summed up. If any specific counter emission is missing, the total will be incorrect and in some cases useless. Aggregation on a collector has nothing to do with this I think, that would happen independently. The problem is, what happens when there is a mismatch between the current state of the application and the previously reported counters. Please keep in mind that we are talking about _counters_ here, not _gauges_.